# fscanf() fails to read number if preceeding string was empty

Tags: c, scanf

This code

```
fscanf(f, "%[^|]|%d", text, &num)
```

Will work if text is longer than 0 bytes, for example the file contains:

```
testtext|89
```

But if the text is 0 bytes long like here:

```
|89
```

then the number read by fscanf will be zero!
What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

According to this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

> at least one character shall be consumed by any specifier. Otherwise the match fails, and the scan ends there.

Comment: thanks for fixing my formatting herohuyongtao, I learned something new about how to format text on this site.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, its more preferable to use strtok() and use '|' as the delimiter.